# Javascript slice() function does not work in Smartface

Tags: javascript, smartface.io

I'm trying to slice an element from my array which has some db records. The follwing codes I tried to do this;

```
var words = Data.execute("select id,word from tbl_Words");
var means = Data.execute("select id,mean from tbl_Meanings");
var rndInd = Math.floor((Math.random() * words.rows.length) + 0);
Pages.pg_Main.lblWord.text = words.rows[rndInd][1];
var rmvItm = words.rows.splice(rndInd,1);
```

Everytime the rmvItm has undefined value,so the splice() function does not work I think. The error occurs as the array does not have normal values I think.

What do you think? How can I use splice() function for this type of array?

Comment: You *think*? Check/debug/trace.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that rows is *array-like*, first push the contents into a real array:

```
var actualArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(words.rows);
```

then splice:

```
var rvItm =actualArray.splice(rndInd,1);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but now I cannot push the rmvItm to words array. How can I push the rmvItm?